# iOS: Splitting a UIScrollView's screenshot to multiple PDF pages for printing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, airprint

I have been trying to get UIScrollView's full length printout. I could get the UIScrollView loaded and could get a part of view in first page of Printout using below piece of code:

```
CGSize viewSize=((UIScrollView*)myScrollview).contentSize;

CGFloat currentHeight=0;
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil);
[(UIScrollView*)myScrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];

while (currentHeight<viewSize.height)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, 792), nil);

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();        

    myScrollview.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,viewSize.width,viewSize.height);
    myScrollview.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, currentHeight,viewSize.width,viewSize.height);
    [myScrollview.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    currentHeight+=612;

    [(UIScrollView*)myScrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, currentHeight) animated:NO];
}
[(UIScrollView*)myScrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

This code displays ScrollView's partial content in first page . I want it to split into multiple pages for printing.

All helps are welcome.

Comment: hi..Did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: @Tommy I did it using first converting it to a full length image & then splitting image to fit A4 size pages.

Comment: Ya i too did the same thing..But while splitting the image it splitted the line into half...i have posted one question regarding this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318853/how-to-align-pdf-pages-while-converting-uiview-into-pdf-data     --- Now am facing this problem

Comment: I too faced this text truncation problem